# Can't find firewall settings for SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to manage firewall settings for my SQL Server database. But there is no firewall option in database settings. The goal of this operation is to allow my IP.

I have a free trial subscription.

[image]

Comment: I just posted an answer earlier today, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35796080/272109), which shows exactly where the firewall setting is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The firewall settings are on the "SqlServer."  When creating a new Azure SQL db instance a SQL server is also created.

Go to Browse>SQL Servers> pick the server that the database is on.

THe Settings on the SQL Server blade will have a Firewall option.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 5):

Just posted this screengrab for a different (unrelated) question, but: You'll find the firewall settings on the Server blade for your given SQL Database:

[image: server firewall]

Here, you'll be able to add your IP (or IP ranges).

Note that you can easily get to the server blade from your database blade, by clicking the linked server name:

[image: server link]

Answer (score -1):

It's in "Security/Networking".

Azure portal screenshot:

[image: Azure portal screen shoot]