# Creating a Firewall rule in Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I'm using Microsoft Azure dreamspark subscription to create a sql database. Even though it allows me to create a DB i cant see any options to create a firewall rule in order to connect my DB from SQL server 2014. Any help?

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question I just answered yesterday, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35804501/272109). Please look at that for your answer.

Comment: That's not the solution I'm looking for. Btw i got the solution by surfing deep in azure portal.

Comment: In order to find the firewall settings in new azure portal select the sql database and click on the server name. Then you will find the firewall rule option in the settings blade. Thank you all