# How to allow client IP access to Microsoft Azure database?

Tags: c#, android, azure

I am developing an Android App. When my App starts this error in below screen shot appears 
[image]

I added a new rule on my server in the Azure portal to allow access for the client IP in error message, but I still have the same error. When I am Trying to execute `sp_set_firewall_rule` I have this:

[image]

I'm using a web service to connect my android App  to  microsoft SQL server database on Azure.

Comment: You really shouldn't connect an Android app directly to the SQL server. It should be hitting a REST API in between.

Comment: This has been covered many times, including [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35804227/cant-find-firewall-settings-for-sql-server/35804501#35804501) I posted, showing exactly where the SQL Database firewall settings are, in the portal. You'll need to add the IP address of your web service. (or add Azure Services to the firewall allow list, if you're hosting your web service inside of a web app).

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidMakogon said, please check the firewall of your Azure SQL Database whether allow access to Azure Service if your web service had been deployed on Azure, please see the figures below.

Fig 1. Browse the overview tab of your SQL Azure on portal
[image]
Fig 2. Enable the option for `Allow access to Azure Service` to **`ON`** 
[image]

Then all of your web services on Azure can access the SQL Database.

Or if your web service had been deployed on other platform for accessing the SQL Database, you need to click `Add client IP`, then the `Client IP address` will be added to the firewall whitelist as the figure below.

[image]